# When attempting to deploy, I get "Restricted from provisioning in this region"

Tags: azure, deployment, paas

When trying to deploy a basic Sitecore 9 XM (Single) Instance via the Azure Portal, I am getting a deployment failure.  After looking at the logs, it seems it is related to the West US region I'm trying to deploy to.  I've got several other resources deployed to this region without any issues.  Anyone else experiences something like this?

Context: Deploying Sitecore 9 XM Single to West US region with the Application Insights deployed to West US 2 via the Azure Portal.

> **OPERATION** IDFD0F8E816C89A7C6
>
> **TRACKING** ID845174e0-aa6f-4fd1-be1c-cd72701bf2dd
>
> **STATUS** BadRequest
>
> **PROVISIONING** STATEFailed
>
> **TIMESTAMP** 12/17/2017, 1:15:26 PM
>
> **DURATION** 0.658175 seconds
>
> **TYPE** Microsoft.Sql/servers
>
> **RESOURCE ID** /subscriptions/fe7149b7-41b2-48c4-8248-8836d1fca6cf/resourceGroups/SitecorePaaS/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sitecorepaas-577780-sql
>
> **STATUSMESSAGE**  {   "code": "45122",   "message": "'MSDN subscriptions are restricted from provisioning in this region. Please
>   choose a different region. For exceptions to this rule please contact
>   Microsoft Support.'",   "target": null,   "details": [
>       {
>         "code": "45122",
>         "message": "'MSDN subscriptions are restricted from provisioning in this region. Please choose a different region. For exceptions to
>   this rule please contact Microsoft Support.'",
>         "target": null,
>         "severity": "16"
>       }   ],   "innererror": [] }
>
> **RESOURCE** sitecorepaas-577780-sql

Reviewing the [Azure data center compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/617478), the West US region is supported.

**Update:**
Even after trying a different region (East US), the deployment failed for me. Turns out this is a [known issue](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/915122) and occurs when using Visual Studio/MSDN Azure subscriptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Sitecore. MSDN Subscriptions (for whatever reason) places restrictions based on the type of account you are using.

If you are using a **Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription** you are limited to the following locations:

- East US
- South Central US
- West Europe
- Southeast Asia
- West US 2
- West Central US

If you are using a **Microsoft Azure Enterprise Subscription** you are limited to the much longer list:

- East US
- West US
- South Central US
- Central US
- North Central US
- East US 2
- North Europe
- West Europe
- Southeast Asia
- East Asia
- Japan West
- Japan East
- Brazil South
- Australia Southeast
- West US 2
- West Central US
- Australia East
- Central India
- South India
- West India
- Canada Central
- Canada East
- UK West
- UK South
- Korea Central
- Korea South

### How Can You Tell What Regions you have

While logged into your Azure account in Windows Azure Powershell, you can run the following command:  `(Get-AzureLocation).Name`

Comment: Thanks, Pete.  Also found another issue related to Application Insights.  Even though the XM topology uses Basic Application Insight plan, the deployment failed for me when using a different region.

Comment: Same error: It is failing for us deploying to `West Europe`. Any other ideas?

Comment: I had to update my spending limit to get past the issue, even though I was using a region which supported basic plan for Application Insights: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/915122